# Create double circle progress chart

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, svg

I would like to create a double circle progress bar with but without any additional library. So I found a solution using SVG and creating one bigger and one smaller circle and then position the smaller one in the middle of the bigger one. But now, I don't know why the inner circle don't has the same width as the outer one, so how can I fix that? 
It should look like

[image: What it should look like]

What I got so far is this: https://jsfiddle.net/equalsound/mf2Lpeeb/2/

```
<div id="leftSidebarAssistant">
  <svg id="leftSidebarAssistantOuterCircle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 34 34">
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="15.9155" class="progress-bar__background" />
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="15.9155" class="progress-bar__progress js-progress-bar" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="leftSidebarAssistantInnerCircle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 34 34">
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="15.9155" class="progress-bar__background" />
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="15.9155" class="progress-bar__progress js-progress-bar" />
  </svg>
</div>


#leftSidebarAssistant {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#leftSidebarAssistantOuterCircle {
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#leftSidebarAssistantInnerCircle {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 78px;
  top: 43px;
}

.progress-bar__background {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #D3DCE9;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progress-bar__progress {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #D3DCE9;
  stroke: #EF2B2B;
  stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s ease-in-out;
}




var percentageComplete = 0.5;
  var strokeDashOffsetValue = 100 - (percentageComplete * 100);
  var progressBar = $(".js-progress-bar");
  progressBar.css("stroke-dashoffset", strokeDashOffsetValue);
```

If I'm missing here something totally obvious I'm sorry, but I've never used svg before.

Comment: it's working properly in the JSfiddle!

Comment: Not really, in Chrome outer circle is wider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it only changing the radius without changing it through css. As an example,

```
<svg id="leftSidebarAssistantOuterCircle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 34 34">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="10.9155" class="progress-bar__background"></circle>
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="10.9155" class="progress-bar__progress js-progress-bar" style="stroke-dashoffset: 50px;"></circle>
```

here, r is the param that only has been changed.remove css width and height from the smaller circle and reduce the radius from the value r.

Comment: By changing the r parameter, it has the same width, but then the value shown is not right anymore. By changing r to 10.9155, the circle displays 75% when he should display 50 :O

Comment: @equalsound The circumference of your original circles is 15.9155, if you take that and multiply by 2 * PI you get approximately 100 which is why your stroke-dashoffset and stroke-dasharray values work with that radius. You need to adjust them for the radius you actually use.

Comment: for that you have any way to change the strokeDashOffsetValue other than 100 to dynamic , according to the the ratio of two radius.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a circle in the same SVG coordinate space and in the same viewport area, but the element containing the inner circle is smaller in pixel size. This makes everything smaller, which gets the circle to the size you want but also makes the stroke appear narrower.